# Why am I getting an never ending loop when reading from a byte.Buffer

Tags: go

Currently I'm writing a program that is reading a buffer from bytes.Buffer. Its supposed to stop reading when it finds the character e. But when I was reading the buffer using a for loop I noticed something odd. When I put the byte reading as part of the for statement I get an infinity loop ([example in go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fV50sqvI8x)):

```
b := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte("uoiea"))
for v, _ := b.ReadByte(); v != 'e'; {
    println("The value is " + string(v))
}
```

But if I removed it and put it inside the for loop, it doesn't ([example in go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1UwENFqj0X)):

```
b := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte("uoiea"))
for ;; {
    v, _ := b.ReadByte()
    println("The value is " + string(v))
    if v == 'e'{
        break
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why is this? I find it that adding the break expression is a very ugly and error prone way to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your [*post statement*](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/1) of the for-loop is empty (you have only *init statement*), so you don't read next byte every iteration (`v` is always `'u'`).

Here is the [fixed version](https://play.golang.org/p/O09kf0f6aI):

```
b := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte("uoiea"))
for v, _ := b.ReadByte(); v != 'e'; v, _ = b.ReadByte() {
    println("The value is " + string(v))
}
```

As mentioned in comments, it's also recommended to check the error to avoid infinite loop when there is no `'e'` byte:

```
b := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte("uoiea"))
for v, e := b.ReadByte(); v != 'e' && e == nil; v, e = b.ReadByte() {
    println("The value is " + string(v))
}
```

`ReadBytes` returns `io.EOF` error when buffer is empty.

Comment: this will lead to an infinite loop if e isn't in the buffer.

Answer (score 3):

You are only reading the buffer once, when you are entering the loop. So the value of `v` will always be `'u'`. You could solve it by reading the next byte in for loop's post statement also:

```
for v, _ := b.ReadByte(); v != 'e'; v, _ = b.ReadByte() {
    // This works as long as there is an 'e' in your buffer
    // Otherwise this goes to infinite loop also, as you are discarding error
```

But your second example is actually better and less ugly way to do this. There's nothing wrong with using `break` in loops like this. Actually it's very idiomatic in Go to write `Read()` loops as conditionless `for` loops and `break` from the loop when appropriate (usually when you get an `io.EOF` error indicating you reached the end of whatever you are reading). It leads to code that is easier to read, especially when there are many conditions that should cause `break`. The idiomatic and preferred (IMHO) way to write the code would be this:

```
b := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte("uoiea"))
for {
    v, err := b.ReadByte()

    if err == io.EOF {
        // End of buffer. Should always break here to avoid infinite loop.
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        // Error other than io.EOF means something went wrong with reading.
        // Should handle it appropriately. Here I'll just panic.
        panic(err)
    }

    if v == 'e' {
        break
    }
    println("The value is " + string(v))
}
```

Which is almost the same as your working example. Just with error checks. But the `io.EOF` error check especially is very important, otherwise you''ll be stuck in infinite loop if there is no `'e'` in your buffer.